# Why do we need 64-bit CPUs?

Tags: 64-bit, cpu, computer-science, cpu-architecture

In software development, 32-bit variables can already meet 99.99% of the requirements. So why do we need 64-bit CPUs?

If it's about addressing issues, couldn't we solve it perfectly like the 8086 did, using "segment registers"? Each segment provides 4GB of space, and with a maximum of 2^32 segments, it would be sufficient for the foreseeable future, even for the next 100 years.

However, making CPUs directly 64-bit not only wastes a significant number of transistors but also consumes a considerable amount of memory space.

Advantages of extending a 32-bit CPU through segment registers:

1. Addressing space issue can be resolved.
2. It can balance memory space spend and software development requirements.
3. Each segment provides 4GB of space, with a maximum of 2^32 segments, which is sufficient for all software usage. If a segment exceeds 4GB, it indicates poor software architecture design, which is highly unfavorable for software maintenance. This approach can instead compel software developers to improve their architecture design.
4. The saved transistor resources can be utilized to add more cores or increase cache size. Additionally, simpler cores contribute to higher clock frequencies.
5. Maximum software compatibility can be achieved, eliminating the confusion caused by the interplay between 32-bit and 64-bit code libraries, as often experienced currently.

Of course, for specialized processors like GPUs, DSPs, TPUs, and others, the number of bits doesn't matter much. These processors are designed for specific purposes, and they can be optimized accordingly without affecting software compatibility. However, when it comes to CPUs as general-purpose processors, these considerations do not apply.

Please note that this is not a professional opinion but rather a personal observation based on my work experience.

Comment: Segment registers make for really ugly compiled code, for models `large` and `huge`, which are the ones that allow addressing more memory than `near` pointers.

Comment: Some Java implementations use 36 bit object pointers, storing only the upper 32 bits and adding the extra 0's upon dereference; all objects have to be 16 bit aligned, which wastes some memory, but they get a 36-bit address space out of 32-bit references.

Comment: "Each segment provides 4GB of space, with a maximum of 2^32 segments, which is sufficient for all software usage. If a segment exceeds 4GB, it indicates poor software architecture design, which is highly unfavorable for software maintenance. "  This is rather opinionated — there are plenty of perfectly good uses for more than 4GB of data.

Comment: We'll never need more than 640K.

Comment: Tangential: sounds like you've never had to deal with segmented memory--it's a workaround, not a "perfect solution". Also tangential: address space and data size are separate things, and not always directly related.

Comment: 32-bit virtual addresses for machines with many more than 4GiB of RAM is inconvenient for kernels.  See Linus Torvalds' rants about PAE (the x86 extension that allowed larger physical addresses on 32-bit x86 without increasing virtual address space, so you could use more than 4GiB of RAM, just not in the same process.)  https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=76912&curpostid=76973 / https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=76912&curpostid=76980 .  (But that's without your segment idea, which would allow accessing more total memory, but not convenient for arrays bigger than 4G.)

Comment: If you're going to extend to wider addresses, it makes sense to have 64-bit integer registers. They're useful for a lot more than addresses, e.g. 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit bitmaps (e.g. bitboard in a chess engine), BigInteger math in 64-bit chunks instead of 32-bit.  Some of the use-cases (like for memcpy) can be handled with wide SIMD vector registers, but not everything.

Answer (score 3):

The statements are incorrect, if they were correct, we wouldn't have x64 and other architectures.

> Addressing space issue can be resolved.

Yes, it is, by having a larger address space provided by x64. Address translation can be executed in fewer steps on x64 than on x32 in some cases.

> It can balance memory space spend and software development requirements.

Not constructive, subjective

> If a segment exceeds 4GB, it indicates poor software architecture design, which is highly unfavorable for software maintenance.

No, many applications require more than 4 GB, for example, machine learning, video and audio processing, scientific computing, research etc. You maybe have a point for *some* consumer applications that keep getting larger, but overall we cannot say this is true for general computing

> The saved transistor resources can be utilized to add more cores or increase cache size. Additionally, simpler cores contribute to higher clock frequencies.

Doesn't seem to be related to the argument of `why we need x64`. The size of x32 and x64 is relatively the same. Not sure I understand this argument.

> Maximum software compatibility can be achieved...

Yes, but the industry moves forward. We used to have 8-bit architecture, some other odd-bit architectures, 16-bit architectures, etc. The industry is very large and intermixed with different requirements and applications. Some CPUs are good for servers, some for mobile devices, some for IoT, some need radioactive protection, and some need to work from wireless energy sources. Overall, the diversity of requirements creates a large pool of needs. x32 architectures satisfy some of them, x64 meets others, but there are many more other architectures that are in use.

Comment: Minor nit: "[...] many applications require more than 4 GB [...]" Sure, but that's orthogonal to how that memory is addressed. The OP is 100% wrong that a > 4G segment means "poor software architecture", but the OP seems to be focusing on a fragment of why something > 4G might be needed--as you point out 